# print abc upercase and lowercase c++ using for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, codeblocks

I am new to c++ and I want to print `"abc"` lower and upercase both like this using console app.

```
Aa 

Aa, Bc 

Aa, Bc, Cc 

Aa, Bc, Cc, Dd
```

and so on to Zz

My simple code is:

```
{ 
char abc;
for(abc = 'A'; abc <= 'Z'; abc++){
    cout<< abc <<",";
}
return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `cout << abc << (char)(abc+32) << ",";`

Comment: sorry bro but (abc+32) what is 32?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif If you add `32` to an uppercase character you get the respective lowercase character.

Comment: This is a homework question. First, see that you need a double loop.

Comment: very funny its an assignment :)

Comment: @Blaze, only on a system that uses ASCII (or superset of ASCII).  C++ is a portable language, remember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying on what you worked before I would suggest to have an outer loop which loops 26 times. And to use `tolower` which converts the uppercase to lowercase but since it returns an integer you should cast it to char.

```
char abc;
int j;
for(int i = 0;i<26;i++)
{
    j = 0;
    for(abc = 'A'; abc <= 'Z' && j<=i; abc++){
        cout<< abc <<static_cast<char>(std::tolower(abc));
        if(j+1 <= i)
            cout<<", ";
        j++;
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `(char)(abc+32)` as an (sigh) upvoted comment suggests. There are several problems in such a small snippet of code:

- you should not use magic numbers. Here `32` is a magic number. What is it? Where does it come from? In ASCII encoding it's `'a' - 'A'`. If you ever need to write this number, don't write `32`, write `'a' - 'A'`. But as we'll see next, there is a problem with this number:
- using `'a' - 'A'` to convert between cases works only for ASCII encodings. `C++` doesn't specify that `char` uses ASCII, although it is the most used encoding. Bottom line: it's not portable. If you use it, make an assertion somewhere that the encoding used is ASCII
- in C++ you should avoid C-style cast, e.g. `(char)(...)`. Use `static_cast` instead.

The simple portable way to convert between cases in C++ is to use [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) and [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower):

```
static_cast<char>(std::tolower(abc))
```

Unfortunately due to the legacy of `C` these functions work on `int` data type (although mostly they interpret it as `char`) so you need the cast.

Comment: so how can i use static_cast in mine case?

Answer (score 0):

Its is actually a simple logic. You need to loops as follows:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            std::cout<<(char)(65 + j)<<(char)(65 + j + 32)<<", ";
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why you need two loops.

Comment: @HelloWorld help is always appreciated. I am also trying to help you any anyone looking over your solution. Your code has several problems. You use 3 magic numbers. This is a serious problem. This alone will never pass a code review. Second you use C-style cast. Not as big of a problem but still, the fix is simple: use `static_cast`. Thirdly you use a non-portable formula.

Comment: so you used 65 because A = 65 and as i new to c++ what is 32  i dint get that